# Postgresql 9.1 - subquery count(*) seq scan - low performance

Tags: postgresql

my query takes long time to execure even it;s limited and orderer by integer value index. As I red the problem is with count(*) in subquery - but I didn't find solution

POSTGRESQL 9.1

QUERY:

```
SELECT
   sms.id,
  (select count(*) 
   from sms_received, sms_recipient 
   where sms.id = sms_recipient.sms_id
     and sms_recipient.id = sms_received.sms_recipient_id ) as pocet_resp
FROM "sms" WHERE done = true
ORDER BY "sms"."id" desc limit 100;
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE Output:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..377992.17 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=58.566..5549.074 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using sms_id on sms  (cost=0.00..1701422117.01 rows=450121 width=4) (actual time=58.564..5548.913 rows=100 loops=1)
         Filter: done
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Aggregate  (cost=3778.61..3778.62 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=55.471..55.471 rows=1 loops=100)
                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=660.83..3778.59 rows=6 width=0) (actual time=55.276..55.456 rows=0 loops=100)
                       Hash Cond: (sms_received.sms_recipient_id = sms_recipient.id)
                       ->  Seq Scan on sms_received  (cost=0.00..2656.33 rows=123033 width=4) (actual time=0.002..30.758 rows=123039 loops=100)
                       ->  Hash  (cost=658.73..658.73 rows=168 width=4) (actual time=0.060..0.060 rows=27 loops=100)
                             Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                             ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on sms_recipient  (cost=5.92..658.73 rows=168 width=4) (actual time=0.036..0.047 rows=27 loops=100)
                                   Recheck Cond: (sms.id = sms_id)
                                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on sms_rec_sms_id  (cost=0.00..5.87 rows=168 width=0) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=140 loops=100)
                                         Index Cond: (sms.id = sms_id)
 Total runtime: 5549.237 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:

```
select    sms.id,
          count(*) 
from      sms
left join sms_received on sms.id            = sms_recipient.sms_id
left join sms_recipient on sms_recipient.id = sms_received.sms_recipient_id
where     sms.done = true and
          sms.id in (select id from sms order by id desc limit 100)
group by  sms.id
order by  sms.id desc
```

You might also try:

```
select    sms.id,
          count(*) 
from      sms
left join sms_received on sms.id            = sms_recipient.sms_id
left join sms_recipient on sms_recipient.id = sms_received.sms_recipient_id
where     sms.done = true and
group by  sms.id
order by  sms.id desc
limit     100
```

... but I'm not sure that it will be as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that issue with trigger - trigger counts inserted rows, so I don't need to use count(*).

Comment: seems like a good idea. count queries are one of the few things that postgresql has trouble with